# Determining a finite subcover for a compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose *(X,τ)* is a compact topological space and *C ⊆ X* is closed. Show that *C* is compact in *(X,τ)*

So far I have come up with:

Let *P* be an open cover of *C*. Thus *C* is closed, then its complement, *P'*, is open.

Now, *P* ∪ { *C '* } is an open cover of X and, therefore, of *C*. Since *X* is compact, *P* ∪ { *C* '} contains a finite subcollection *P '* that also covers X and, therefore, covers *C*.

If *C '* is not in *P*', then *P*' is a finite subcollection of *P* that covers *C*. Otherwise, if we remove *C*' from *P*', we get a finite subcollection of *P* that covers 
*C*.

So, every open cover of C contains a finite subcover. It follows C is compact

I'm assuming I will need to show more proof as to how you would reach this conclusion

Comment: If you’re supposed to show that $C$ is a compact *subset* of $X$, then your proof is just fine as it is. If you’re supposed to show that $C$ is a compact *subspace* of $X$, then, as Mike Miller notes in his answer, you have to start with a cover of $C$ by sets that are (relatively) open in $C$ and expand them to open sets in $X$ before applying your argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful when constructing the open cover of $X$ - the elements of the open cover of $C$ don't have to be open in $X$.

To do this, remember the definition of the subspace topology - $U$ is open in $C$ iff there's an $U' \subset X$ such that $U' \cap C = U$. Now pick *these* open sets and cover $X$ with them. Continue your proof from there - it shouldn't take more than minor edits to make it work.